# How to use long id in Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, int, long-integer, bigint

How can I change the (default) type for ActiveRecord's IDs? int is not long enough, I would prefer long. I was surprised that there is no :long for the migrations - does one just use some decimal?

Comment: NOTE, things change dramatically in Rails 5, including defaulting to `bigint`, so take all of the below answers with a grain of salt if you're on Rails 5+.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Credits to http://moeffju.net/blog/using-bigint-columns-in-rails-migrations

```
class CreateDemo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :demo, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :id, :limit => 8
    end
  end
end
```

- See the option `:id => false` which disables the automatic creation of the id field
- The `t.integer :id, :limit => 8` line will produce a 64 bit integer field

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't create the id column as primary key etc.

Comment: True. I did that with raw SQL. I've read the soruce, and I did not find any option to do that intelligently (3.0.7) . That's a shame. But hey! 3.1.0 is out for a while! Good luck!

Comment: I found this because I was looking for *any* field to be set to bigint in postgres. The :id information is a bonus!

Comment: @EricWang It was a long time ago, I don't do Ruby on Rails (or even) nowdays. But this one I used regularly and I don't remember having any regression in relation to a "classic" identifier.

Comment: @Notinlist The question is about `long id`, not just `long`, thus the column is better be declared as primary key.

Answer (score 44):

To set the **default primary key column type**, the migration files are not the place to mess with.

Instead, just stick this at the bottom of your `config/environment.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
```

And all your tables should be created with the intended column type for `id`:

```
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
```

After you've done what you've set out to do... the next question is probably "How do I make my foreign key columns the same column type?" since it does not make sense to have primary key `people.id` as `bigint(20) unsigned`, and `person_id` be `int(11)` or anything else?

For those columns, you can refer to the other suggestions, e.g.

```
t.column :author_id, 'BIGINT UNSIGNED'
t.integer :author_id, :limit => 8
```

**UPDATE**: @Notinlist, to use arbitrary column for primary key on arbitrary tables you need to do the `create_table-change_column` dance:

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  # column definitions here..
end
change_column :users, :id, :float # or some other column type
```

e.g. if I wanted `guid` instead of auto-increment integers,

```
create_table(:users, :primary_key => 'guid') do |t|
  # column definitions here..
end
change_column :users, :guid, :string, :limit => 36
```

Comment: This is a useful approach, but is there any way to make this database-independent or is that just the price one pays for this need?

Comment: What if I don't want to use `bigint` for all my tables, just for some?

Comment: then 1) you should leave the config/environment.rb alone. 2) issue a "change_column" after your "create_table" to use bigint (see the last snippet)

Comment: Looks like `:primary_key => 'guid'` then changing to string won't work.  If I'm understanding correctly, a reference to `primary_key` in a migration, by definition, creates an auto-incrementing field, so it wouldn't work on strings. See Rudd Zwolinski's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column).

Comment: @choonkeat, you're right, that works. Looks like with sqlite3, `change_column` completely drops and re-adds the table (see `development.log`). So `"guid" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL` becomes simply `"guid" varchar(36)`. It is no longer a primary key, NULL is allowed, and it is not indexed. In PostgreSQL, `:guid` is changed with ALTER COLUMN` so it's still the primary key and still auto-increments (1, 2, 3).

Comment: I would **very** much recommend against create-then-change, at least in Rails 2.3.x.  If you check your db/schema.rb file after running this migration, you'll notice it has no mention of your changes, so anyone creating your DB from the schema (like tests) will not have the same structure.

Comment: For mysql2 adapter add:

`if ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters.local_constant_names.include?("Mysql2Adapter")
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
end
`

Answer (score 7):

This is hard to set for the primary key with migrations because Rails puts it in automatically.

You can change any column later like this:

`change_column :foobars, :something_id, 'bigint'`

You can specify non-primary IDs as custom types in your initial migration like this:

```
create_table :tweets do |t|
  t.column :twitter_id, 'bigint'
  t.column :twitter_in_reply_to_status_id, 'bigint'
end
```

Where I have "bigint" you can put any text that your database would use for the database column type you want to use (e.g., "unsigned long").

If you need your id column to be a bigint, the easiest way to do it would be to create the table, then change the column in the same migration with change_column.

With PostgreSQL and SQLite, schema changes are atomic so this won't leave your database in a weird state if the migration fails. With MySQL you need to be more careful.

Comment: Thanks - it seems for a "normal" column using limit => 8 would do the trick, but for the primary_key this does not work. For MySQL I have now used custom SQL with execute. Would prefer change_column, but wouldn't that have the same problem as initial creation, namely that :limit => 8 would not be supported for primary key columns?

Comment: No, you can use change_column with the primary key, like this: change_column :foobars, :id, "bigint". So you'd create the table and then immediately change the ID column to be a bigint. I still don't think using :limit with an int column is going to work (with MySQL anyway) because int's max size is 2**31-1 no matter what.

Comment: OK, I just looked it up in the Rails docs and if you do t.column :foobar, :int, :limit => 8 you will get a bigint.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Rails API documentation, the possible options for type are:

```
:string
:text
:integer
:float
:decimal
:datetime
:timestamp
:time
:date
:binary
:boolean
```

You can use :decimal, or you can execute a command directly if you need to:

```
class MyMigration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE my_table ADD id LONG"
  end
end
```

As wappos pointed out, you can use auxiliary options like :limit to tell ActiveRecord how large you want the column to be. So you would use the :int column with a larger :limit.

Comment: "As wappos pointed out, you can use auxiliary options like :limit to tell ActiveRecord how large you want the column to be. So you would use the :int column with a larger :limit."

I don't think that will work if what he wants is larger than integer will hold. Setting a larger limit won't change the maximum size.

Comment: in fact :primary_key does not have the :limit option, so this does not work for the primary key column.

Comment: I just looked it up in the Rails docs and if use :limit => 8 on an integer column you will get a bigint. I did not realize that.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone needs this to work with PostgreSQL, create an initializer like this:

```
# config/initializers/bigint_primary_keys.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = 'bigserial primary key'
```

Because of lazy loading in Rails 3.2 (and maybe even earlier versions), `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter` won't be required until you establish the database connection.

Comment: You don't need to establish a connection to do the require, just require the appropriate adapter, e.g. for pg: require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter', mysql: require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter', sqlite: require 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter', oracle: require 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter'.

Answer (score 4):

In `rails4`, you can do it.

Following is an example to create a `Dummy` model in `rails4` & `postgres`,

**xxx_migrate_dummies.rb:**

```
class CreateDummies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dummies, :id => false do |t|
      t.column :id, :serial8, primary_key: true
      t.string :name, :limit => 50, null: false
      t.integer :size, null: false

      t.column :create_date, :timestamptz, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**What it did:**

- It use `serial8` as id type, which is 64 bit integer, and define it as `primary key`.
- It use `timestamptz` as datetime type, which contain the timezone info, this is important for a application that go across multiple timezones.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3, MySQL:

```
t.column :foobar, :int, :limit => 8
```

Does not give me a bigint, only an int. However,

```
t.column :twitter_id, 'bigint'
```

works fine. (Although it does tie me to MySQL.)

Comment: 'bigint' as a column type should also work on PostgreSQL. I used it the other day for an int column of size 8.

Comment: Cool!  MySQL and PostgreSQL are the only ones that seem at all relevant to me.  Actually, they're now owned by the same org I hear..

Comment: MySQL is now owned by Oracle, but this is not the case for PostgreSQL, which probably means that it will thrive more :)

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from other solutions, adjusted for what worked for me recently.

Add to a file in `config/initializers`. It declares a new column type (adapted from chookeat's suggestion).

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:long_primary_key] = "BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"`

Migrations that use a long id are as such:

```
    create_table :notification_logs, :id => false do |t|

      t.column :id, :long_primary_key
      # ...
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem called [activerecord-native_db_types_override](https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-native_db_types_override) that lets you alter the datatypes that will be used in your migrations.

In your Gemfile, add:

```
gem 'activerecord-native_db_types_override'
```

then in config/environment.rb, to use long ids in postgres, add:

```
NativeDbTypesOverride.configure({
  postgres: {
    primary_key: { name: "bigserial primary key"}
  }
})
```

See its [README](https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-native_db_types_override) for up-to-date info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users, id: :bigserial do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Correction to how to change the default `primary key` column type:

Instead of:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
```

you should do:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "BIGINT(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
```

or else you won't be able to add `foreign key` restrictions in the database layer.

Comment: Could you provide more detail in the difference between `BIGINT(**8**)` and `BIGINT`, and how it affects foreign key creation in MySQL? (I tried googling and searching the MySQL documentation, but the special characters are borking the search.)

Comment: I suspect the OP was just putting those asterisks in for emphasis. I edited to remove them. He's also wrong, BTW -- precision values for numbers in MySQL only affect their display width, and there's no need for them in this case.

Comment: Note, as of Rails ~5, overriding the `primary_key` like this no longer works. It is simply ignored. The good news is that as of Rails ~5, the default column type for primary keys is `bigint`. However, it is not `unsigned`. If you want `unsigned` to be the default, please look at this Github issue and show your support: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40967