# Using Rails, how can I set my primary key to not be an integer-typed column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, primary-key

I'm using Rails migrations to manage a database schema, and I'm creating a simple table where I'd like to use a non-integer value as the primary key (in particular, a string). To abstract away from my problem, let's say there's a table `employees` where employees are identified by an alphanumeric string, e.g. `"134SNW"`.

I've tried creating the table in a migration like this:

```
create_table :employees, {:primary_key => :emp_id} do |t|
    t.string :emp_id
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
end
```

What this gives me is what seems like it completely ignored the line `t.string :emp_id` and went ahead and made it an integer column. Is there some other way to have rails generate the PRIMARY_KEY constraint (I'm using PostgreSQL) for me, without having to write the SQL in an `execute` call?

**NOTE**: I know it's not best to use string columns as primary keys, so please no answers just saying to add an integer primary key. I may add one anyway, but this question is still valid.

Comment: I have the same problem and I would love to see an answer for this.  None of the suggestions so far have worked.

Comment: None of them will work if you're using Postgres. Dan Chak's "Enterprise Rails" has some tips for using natural/composite keys.

Comment: Beware that when you use something like: <!-- language: lang-rb --> execute "ALTER TABLE employees ADD PRIMARY KEY (emp_id);" Although the table constraint is set correctly after running `rake db:migrate` The auto-generated schema definition does not contain this constraint!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've determined it's not possible to do it without using `execute`.

### Why it doesn't work

By examining the ActiveRecord source, we can find the code for `create_table`:

In [`schema_statements.rb`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5a7d31913bb16977ec85d55de34ac0d79b512d62/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L161):

```
def create_table(table_name, options={})
  ...
  table_definition.primary_key(options[:primary_key] || Base.get_primary_key(table_name.to_s.singularize)) unless options[:id] == false
  ...
end
```

So we can see that when you try to specify a primary key in the `create_table` options, it creates a primary key with that specified name (or, if none is specified, `id`). It does this by calling the same method you can use inside a table definition block: `primary_key`.

In [`schema_statements.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a63f7a136401b59db52fb802180f6c9793d83bc2/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L89):

```
def primary_key(name)
  column(name, :primary_key)
end
```

This just creates a column with the specified name of type `:primary_key`. This is set to the following in the standard database adapters:

```
PostgreSQL: "serial primary key"
MySQL: "int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
SQLite: "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL"
```

### The workaround

Since we're stuck with these as the primary key types, we have to use `execute` to create a primary key that is not an integer (PostgreSQL's `serial` is an integer using a sequence):

```
create_table :employees, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.string :emp_id
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
end
execute "ALTER TABLE employees ADD PRIMARY KEY (emp_id);"
```

And as [Sean McCleary mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column/1429146#1429146), your ActiveRecord model should set the primary key using `set_primary_key`:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :emp_id
  ...
end
```

Comment: the workaround will make the rake db:test:clone or rake db:schema:load to create emp_id as integer column.

Comment: actually, now you should be using `self.primary_key=` instead of `set_primary_key`, since the latter is deprecated.

Comment: Here is the *only* solution that worked for me.  I hope it helps others:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15297616/679628

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when you setup your database from `schema.rb` `emp_id` will be an `integer` type column again. It seems that `schema.rb` cannot store `execute "ALTER TABLE employees ADD PRIMARY KEY (emp_id);"` in any way.

Comment: @DonnyKurnia @Tintin81 You can switch the schema dump from `schema.rb` to `structure.sql` via `config.active_record.schema_format` setting, which may be either `:sql` or `:ruby`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for

Comment: for those who want to use `:ruby` schema format, there is a solution not to use `execute` statement, described here: http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Comment: There's one last alternative to responses from @DonnyKurnia @Tintin81 and @SvilenIvanov if you really need the `db:test:clone` and `db:schema:load` processes to work (which we did for rspec tests). It's not ideal, but it's lower risk than changing to `structure.sql` if you have a large app.
It is to have _no_ primary key in the DB. Instead, add a unique index on it using `add_index :employees, :emp_id, unique: true`, and set the primary_key in the model code.
That way, you get DB uniqueness and performance, Rails treats it as a primary_key, and your `schema.rb` matches your DB perfectly.

Answer (score 21):

**This works:**

```
create_table :employees, :primary_key => :emp_id do |t|
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
end
change_column :employees, :emp_id, :string
```

It may not be pretty, but the end result is exactly what you want.

Comment: Finally!  This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Do we have to specify code for migration down as well? or is Rails smart enough to know what to do when migrated down?

Comment: For the down migration: `drop_table :employees`

Comment: Unfortunately, this method also leaves us with a `schema.rb` that is not in sync ... it will retain the `:primary_key => :emp_id` declaration, but when `rake db:schema:load` is called, as it is at the beginning of tests, it will produce an integer column.  However, it may be the case that if you switch to using `structure.sql` (config option) tests would retain the settings and use that file to load the schema.

Answer (score 18):

I have one way of handling this. The executed SQL is ANSI SQL so it will likely work on most ANSI SQL compliant relational databases.  I have tested that this works for MySQL.

Migration:

```
create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
    t.string :oid, :limit => 10, :null => false
    ...
end
execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (oid);"
```

In your model do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_primary_key :oid
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 11):

In Rails 5 you can do

```
create_table :employees, id: :string do |t|
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
end
```

See [create_table documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table).

Comment: Worth noting that you'd need to add some sort of `before_create :set_id` method in the model to assign the value of the primary key

Answer (score 10):

I have tried it in Rails 4.2. To add your custom primary key, you can write your migration as :

```
# tracks_ migration
class CreateTracks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tracks, :id => false do |t|
      t.primary_key :apple_id, :string, limit: 8
      t.string :artist
      t.string :label
      t.string :isrc
      t.string :vendor_id
      t.string :vendor_offer_code

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :tracks, :label
  end
end
```

While looking at the documentation of [`column(name, type, options = {})`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition/column) and read the line :

> The `type` parameter is normally one of the migrations native types, which is one of the following: :primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :time, :date, :binary, :boolean.

I got the above ides as i have shown. Here is the table meta data after running this migration :

```
[arup@music_track (master)]$ rails db
psql (9.2.7)
Type "help" for help.

music_track_development=# \d tracks
                    Table "public.tracks"
      Column       |            Type             | Modifiers
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 apple_id          | character varying(8)        | not null
 artist            | character varying           |
 label             | character varying           |
 isrc              | character varying           |
 vendor_id         | character varying           |
 vendor_offer_code | character varying           |
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 title             | character varying           |
Indexes:
    "tracks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (apple_id)
    "index_tracks_on_label" btree (label)

music_track_development=#
```

And from Rails console :

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
=> Unable to load pry
>> Track.primary_key
=> "apple_id"
>>
```

Comment: The problem comes is, though, that the `schema.rb` file that gets generated doesn't reflect the `string` type for the primary key, so when generating the database with a `load`, the primary key gets created as an integer.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it is possible to do using this approach:

```
create_table :widgets, :id => false do |t|
  t.string :widget_id, :limit => 20, :primary => true

  # other column definitions
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "widget_id"
end
```

That will make the column widget_id the primary key for the Widget class, then it is up to you to populate the field when objects are created.  You should be able to do so using the before create callback.

So something along the lines of

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "widget_id"

  before_create :init_widget_id

  private
  def init_widget_id
    self.widget_id = generate_widget_id
    # generate_widget_id represents whatever logic you are using to generate a unique id
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not work for me, at least not in PostgreSQL. No primary key is specified at all.

Comment: Hmm interesting I've tested it with MySQL on Rails 2.3.2 - could be related to version of rails too perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure--I don't think it's the version of Rails. I'm using Rails 2.3.3.

Comment: Unfortunately an actual primary key is not set for the table using this approach.

Comment: This approach works with Rails 4.2 and Postgresql, at least. I've tested, but you need to use `primary_key: true` instead of just `primary` given in answer

Answer (score 8):

I am on Rails 2.3.5 and my following way works with SQLite3

```
create_table :widgets, { :primary_key => :widget_id } do |t|
  t.string :widget_id

  # other column definitions
end
```

There is no need for :id => false.

Comment: sorry, but widget_id changed to integer when i apply your tecnique...do you have eny solution?

Comment: This no longer works, at least not in ActiveRecord 4.1.4. It gives the following error: `you can't redefine the primary key column 'widgets'. To define a custom primary key, pass { id: false } to create_table.`

Answer (score 4):

After nearly every solution which says "this worked for me on X database", I see a comment by the original poster to the effect of "didn't work for me on Postgres." The real issue here may in fact be the Postgres support in Rails, which is not flawless, and was probably worse back in 2009 when this question originally posted. For instance, if I remember correctly, if you're on Postgres, you basically can't get useful output from `rake db:schema:dump`.

I am not a Postgres ninja myself, I got this info from Xavier Shay's excellent PeepCode video on Postgres. That video actually overlooks a library by Aaron Patterson, I think Texticle but I could be remembering wrong. But other than that it's pretty great.

Anyway, if you're running into this problem on Postgres, see if the solutions work in other databases. Maybe use `rails new` to generate a new app as a sandbox, or just create something like

```
sandbox:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/sandbox.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

in `config/database.yml`.

And if you can verify that it is a Postgres support issue, and you figure out a fix, please contribute patches to Rails or package your fixes in a gem, because the Postgres user base within the Rails community is pretty large, mainly thanks to Heroku.

Comment: Downvoting for FUD and inaccuracy. I've used Postgres on most of my Rails projects since 2007. Postgres support in Rails is excellent, and there's no problem with the schema dumper.

Comment: on the one hand, it's true that Postgres wasn't the problem here. on the other, here's a pg-only schema dumper bug from 2009 https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2418 and here's another one https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2514

Comment: There was a decided issue with Rails and Postgres surrounding the Postgres 8.3 update where they (correctly, IMO) decided to change over to the SQL standard for string literals and quoting.  The Rails adapter didn't check Postgres versions and had to be monkeypatched for a while.

Comment: @Judson Interesting. I never ran into that.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to this that works with Rails 3:

The migration  file:

```
create_table :employees, {:primary_key => :emp_id} do |t|
  t.string :emp_id
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
end
```

And in the employee.rb model:

```
self.primary_key = :emp_id
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick that worked for me on Rails 3 and MySQL was this:

```
create_table :events, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.string :id, :null => false
end

add_index :events, :id, :unique => true
```

So:

1. use :id => false so as not to generate an integer primary key
2. use the desired datatype, and add :null => false
3. add a unique index on that column

Seems that MySQL converts the unique index on a non null column to a primary key!

Comment: In Rails 3.22 with MySQL 5.5.15 it creates an unique key only, but not primary key.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the option :id => false

```
create_table :employees, :id => false, :primary_key => :emp_id do |t|
    t.string :emp_id
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
end
```

Comment: This does not work for me, at least not in PostgreSQL. No primary key is specified at all.

Comment: This approach will omit the id column but the primary key will not actually be set on the table.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution,

Inside Employee model why can't we add code that will check for uniqueness in coloumn, for ex: Assume Employee is Model in that you have EmpId which is string then for that we can add  **":uniqueness => true"** to EmpId

```
    class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :EmpId , :uniqueness => true
    end
```

I am not sure that this is solution but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread I stumbled across... but I'm kind of shocked no one mentioned DataMapper.

I find if you need to stray out of the ActiveRecord convention, I've found that it is a great alternative. Also its a better approach for legacy and you can support the database "as-is".

[Ruby Object Mapper](http://rom-rb.org/) (DataMapper 2) holds a lot of promise and build on AREL principles, too!

Answer (score 1):

Adding index works for me, I'm using MySql btw.

```
create_table :cards, {:id => false} do |t|
    t.string :id, :limit => 36
    t.string :name
    t.string :details
    t.datetime :created_date
    t.datetime :modified_date
end
add_index :cards, :id, :unique => true
```