# In Ruby on Rails, how can a model "has_many" and "belong_to" using a different field other than primary ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, activerecord, one-to-many

I am trying building a simple project from scratch using Rails 3.  Usually, the models are like:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :awards
end

class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

and we use the `award.id` and `student.id` to get the corresponding records.

But what if it is

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stock_quotes
end


class StockQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :company
end
```

In this case, we can use the symbol of the company, such as `MSFT` or `GOOG` to identify the company, instead of using the company.id.  For example, in stock_quotes, we can store the symbol of the company directly instead of using `company.id`.  In this case, is there a way to specify it in the models?

Answer (score 1):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Check out :primary_key and :foreign_key options

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Slawosz' answer, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column) about non-integer primary keys is also relevant to your question. IMHO, it would be easier to just use integer id's like in the example of `Award` and `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

Slawosz has the answer right. To be verbose (and for the next time I search this) it should be like this:

```
#company
has_many :stock_quotes, :primary_key => :symbol

#stock_quote
belongs_to :company, :foreign_key => :symbol
```

Comment: are you sure?  It seems that both of them need to be `:primary_key => :symbol, :foreign_key => :symbol`

Comment: I'm not totally sure on that (it's definitely untested) but it works the same way as if StockQuote had a column :company_id . Rails would automatically pick up on the foreign key (company_id) to Company and then use the PK :id to do the join. This is overriding each other. If anything, I may have them reversed.