# Does a Rails foreign_key have to be an integer?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

We have some imported data from a 3rd party which provides non-integer unique ids.

In Rails 2.2.2 we were able to use `:foreign_key` on our `has_many` relationships with a non-integer column and it worked.

But we are now upgrading to Rails 2.3.8 and it seems to force the foreign_key to an integer.  Has anyone found a way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column/1434819#1434819), the procedure has to be completed using `execute`:

```
create_table :employees, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.string :emp_id
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
end
execute "ALTER TABLE employees ADD PRIMARY KEY (emp_id);"
```

And as [Sean McCleary mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column/1429146#1429146), your ActiveRecord model should set the primary key using `set_primary_key`:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :emp_id
  ...
end
```

Comment: This answer talks about having a non-integer primary_key, what about foreign key? What about using t.references and Rails creating a another_table_id as integer? I ended up using t.string another_table_id instead of using t.references.