# rails3 bigint primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, primary-key, bigint

I would like to create a `bigint` (or `string` or whatever that is not `int`) typed primary key field under Rails 3.

I have a given structure of data, for example:

```
things
------
id bigint primary_key
name char(32)
```

The approach I'm currently trying to push:

```
create_table :things, :id => false do |t| # That prevents the creation of (id int) PK
  t.integer :id, :limit => 8 # That makes the column type bigint
  t.string :name, :limit => 32
  t.primary_key :id # This is perfectly ignored :-(
end
```

The column type will be correct, but the primary key option will not be present with sqlite3 and I suspect that this is the case for MySQL too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had that myself not long ago and found the answer here: [Using Rails, how can I set my primary key to not be an integer-typed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column/1434819#1434819)

You need to set primary_key: false and then use a custom statement before you execute the migration.

**EDIT 1:** You need to check your database docs for the exact query to perform. It is executed as a regular SQL statement and needs to be database specific. The example in the question I referred to is for Postgre SQL. If you are on MySQL you might have to change that.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE things ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);`: Is this something that runs on all databases?

Comment: Can I write a case-when structure for that at the migration? Can I test for database variant there?

Comment: I'm sure you can but I don't know how. Can you use Rails.env instead?

Comment: In `self.up`: `self.connection.adapter_name`. See `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter`'s documentation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I think the easiest way for a table

```
accounts 
id bigint primary key 
name char
```

is

```
create_table :accounts do |t|
t.string :name
end
change_column :accounts, :id , "bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"
```

Comment: Almost there. Just do `change_column :accounts, :id, 'bigint'`

Comment: you loose auto increment if you just use 'bigint'

Comment: @skalogirou I just did `change_column :my_primary, :id, 'bigint'` and worked fine, did not lose auto-increment (on Rails 4, Postgres)

Comment: In MySQL/MariaDB, if you just use 'bigint' you will lose auto increment

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL you can use "SERIAL" which is alias for "BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"

```
class ChangeUserIdToBigint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :id, 'SERIAL'
  end
end
```

Comment: You're right, `SERIAL` works with the notable difference that it adds a `unique` key index to that column as well.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who came here (like I did) in an effort to figure out how to make a custom `id` column that uses `bigint` instead of `int`, what I didn't realize is that for Rails 5.1 and above, `bigint` is the default type for `id`

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266

Comment: NOTE, althought Rails 5.1 makes the default for primary key columns `bigint`, it is `signed`, not `unsigned`. To make the default `unsigned`, check out this Github issue and show your support there: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40967

Answer (score 0):

[skalogirou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514828/237838) is good but the change will not be reflected in schema.rb. So the tasks like `db:schema:load` and `db:test:clone` will not create identical DB structure.

The required workaround is to enhance `db:schema:load` and db:test:clone rake tasks as described here:
http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/09/30/changing-the-primary-key-type-in-ruby-on-rails-models/

This is what I used based on that workaround:

```
namespace :my_app do
  namespace :db do
    task :after_schema_load_and_db_test_clone => :environment do
    puts 'Changing primary key for :my_table'
    query = 'ALTER TABLE <my_table> CHANGE id id bigint DEFAULT NULL auto_increment'
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
  end
end


Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].enhance do
  ::Rake::Task['my_app:db:after_schema_load_and_db_test_clone'].invoke
end

Rake::Task['db:test:clone'].enhance do
  ::Rake::Task['my_app:db:after_schema_load_and_db_test_clone'].invoke
end
```

Comment: I found it easier to switch to a SQL dump: `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in config/application.rb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all tables in Postgres you will need to run this code

```
class ConvertIntToBigint < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    query = <<-SQL
      SELECT tablename AS "tablename"
      FROM pg_tables
      WHERE schemaname = 'public';
    SQL
    connection.execute(query).each do |element|
      if column_exists?(element['tablename'], :id, :integer)
        change_table(element['tablename']) {|t| t.change :id, :bigint }
      end
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```