# Rails: How to use BIGINT as Primary Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, primary-key, ruby-on-rails-5, biginteger

I've read through a lot of articles discussing how to use `BIGINT` as primary keys in Rails, but it seems like all of them are outdated.

How can I use BIGINT's for my primary keys, preferrably by just setting this globally. (i am aware of the differences in performance)

Things I've tried:

- http://www.mccartie.com/2016/12/05/rails-5.1.html
- https://moeffju.net/blog/bigints-in-rails-as-primary-keys
- and a lot more I cannot remember

Comment: Have you tried any of those supposedly outdated ways?

Comment: [should I close it as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708868/rails-4-mysql-bigint-primary-key-issues-and-errors)

Comment: I've tried all I found

Comment: @jonhue: could you post some ways that you tried and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your app was natively built in `rails '>= 5.1'`, your primary keys should already be `BIGINT`. By "natively built" I mean that your migrations were initially run with that Rails version (as opposed to running them in < 5.1 and then updating the gem later)

If they are not already `BIGINT`, you can use the migration action found in the source below, pasted here for convenience:

`change_column :your_table_name, :id, :bigint`

Source: http://www.mccartie.com/2016/12/05/rails-5.1.html

Comment: I looked at that article before, but is explicitly speaks about Rails > 5.1. As I've stated in the post, I am using Rails 5.0.2. As far as I know, Rails 5.1 has not been released on rubygems yet...

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I misread.

That said, did you try the migration?

Comment: Tried it on rails 4.2 and it works smoothly :)
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tries this code in migration file?

```
  def change
    create_table :table_name, id: false do |t|
      t.bigint :id, null: false
      t.index :id, name: "pk_table_name", unique: true
    end
  end
```

And in model:

```
class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :id
end
```

Comment: What is `"pk_table_name"`? And as far is I know `t.integer :id, limit: 8` is the correct expression for a BIGINT in Rails, or is that a Rails 5.1 thing?

Comment: yes you are right: `t.integer :id, limit: 5, null: false, options: 'PRIMARY KEY'`
and `pk_table_name ` is the indexing name.