# How to change the column name while generating model in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

here i am trying to customize the column name in mysql.
i have generated the model in rails using

```
rails generate scaffold my_products product_category:string product_name:string
```

when i do `rake db:migrate` the id is generated by default. but i want to change the `id` column name to `product_id`,which will be same as ID with primary key, so it will be easy for querying and other manipulation.

How should i do it?

or can i change id to product_id while generating model?

Comment: http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/
change your migration file accordingly to the documentation. you need to set `id: false` and `t.primary_key :product_id`

Comment: see,, if it helps you or not http://stackoverflow.com/a/30272522/2767755

Comment: I'm struggling to think how this helps querying etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your migration file should look like

```
class CreateMyProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_products, id: false do |t|
      t.primary_key :product_id
      t.string :product_category
      t.string :product_name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure you add `id: false` and set the primary_key as product_id