# In Rails/ActiveRecord 3, how do I change the default primary key type for MySQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, how do you change the default primary key type to, say, `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`

In my case I'm only interested in MySQL.

For Rails 2, you can see the answer to "How do I use long IDs in Rails?"[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066340/how-to-use-long-id-in-rails-applications)

In Rails 3, however, this will throw an error.  I'm not sure if that's because the class is no long used, or if the code needs to go in the same place.  You can see in `active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb` that the `NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES` constant is still defined.

What's the correct way to achieve the same effect in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the connection adapters are now loaded lazily after all the initializers have run.

Try explicitly requiring the code module you're monkey-patching:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter'
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] =
    "BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY".freeze
```

I don't know if adding this to `config/environment.rb` still works.  I added it to `config/application.rb` instead anyway because it seemed more appropriate.

Comment: I tried doing that in the most recent Rails 3 version (sticking it at the end of application.rb) and the migrations don't respect it for some reason.

Comment: Well, it did work for me on Rails 3.0.3 with a PostgreSQL database (changing the corresponding option in the PostgreSQLAdapter).  What's your exact Rails version?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using mysql2 adapter, change the above code to:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = ....
```