# Ruby on Rails App with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, types

Rails 3.2 , Using MySQL database . What datatype should I use to the field of Phone number?

Am currently using t.integer, but its not supporting the length of Phone number which has more than 12 digits. Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 64-bit integers (which can store numbers as high as 9,223,372,036,854,775,807), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5870148/2608804).

However, I think that phone numbers are better stored as strings than integers, since you may need to represent leading zeroes.