# Is it possible to use a long id in Rails applications and persist it through to the test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

#### The setup

We have some tables which have very high `id` values, and as such they are `bigints` in production, which was achieved by running migrations changing the id columns including `limit: 8`. This methodology is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5870148/2240218

Those migrations don't modify `db/schema.rb`, so when we run `rake db:test:prepare`, the test database is created with normal 4-byte integer columns which have a [maximum of 2.1 billion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html) (for what it's worth, we are using Postgres).

---

#### A note about our ids

For legacy reasons they are tied to being foreign keys from a third party system. We would ideally be using the `id` column as an internal surrogate primary key and the third party key would be a separate column entirely (which would remove this whole problem), but the overhead in this change is beyond what I'm trying to get to at the moment.

---

#### The problem

I'm trying to put some integration tests in place with real-world data, and some of these have an `id` larger than 2.1billion. We will have some calls into these external systems when running the tests (which we'll ultimately stub using VCR) so they need to be correct. However, when I try and use this data it blows up because the value is too large for the column in the test database.

**So my question is**: is there any non-massively-hacky way to ensure these `id` columns are `bigints` in the test database after running `db:test:prepare`?

Comment: Would switching from schema.rb to structure.sql fix it?

Comment: Thanks @PhilipHallstrom - yes, that looks like it would be work fine!  I hadn't come across structures.sql before, can you pop that in as an answer with an example and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the schema format from `:ruby` to `:sql` so that your schema dump is pure SQL. This should keep those large integers intact (as well as any stored procs, etc you might have).

In config/application.rb:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps