# Rails doesn't see Bigint id in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have routes in Rails application:

```
resources :products do
  get 'preview', to: 'products#preview', on: :member
    #member do
    #  get 'preview'
    #end
end
```

which defines route '/products/:id/preview'.

Products.id is bigint in a database.

When I open URL '/products/15/preview' it works fine.
But when I open it with big id = 67500 which is bigger than max value for integer = 65535:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/67500/preview
```

it shows 404 error. Here id = 67500 which is bigger than Integer (65535) and the route doesn't work.

How to make Rails recognize id of BIGINT type ?

Comment: Please, post your controller code

Comment: you should change the `id` column of products `create_table :products, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :id, :limit => 8
    end` by this

Comment: Controller:

def preview
    id = params[:id]

    @row = Product.find(id)
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rajarshi Das` is right - this is not a routes problem, but a **database** one.

---

**DB**

The *routes* part of your system will just be sending the required params to your controller. It has no bearing on the size of the number you're sending - it's "dumb".

The problem appears to be with your database - unable to look up the `id` you've requested.

To fix this, you need to change the `id` column to [accommodate larger numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066340/how-to-use-long-id-in-rails-applications):

```
$ rails g migration ChangeIDProducts

#db/migrate/change_id_products______.rb
class ChangeIdProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_column :products, :id, limit: 20
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I already have column id of type bigint in the database. I restart server and now it works. Thanks!